# Using libsass with compass

Tags: compass, libsass

Exactly as the title says. Compilation times over 50 seconds are unacceptable. So, is there a way, let's say: a single (partial) file with compass magic (like sprite mixins, etc.), and the rest of files with pure sass?

I'm considering moving to less (reference importing), and substituting all compass tricks with additional grunt tasks, but I'm more comfortable around sass than less.

I saw [those](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/82) [tickets](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/78), but I hoped there would be a way to compile a single file with compass, and the rest to be merged with libsass (I sometimes use sass 3.3 syntax, but if I can gain better compile times I can revert to 3.2).

Did anyone succeed in such configuration?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In our case (>100.000 LoCSS), we succesfully moved from grunt-contrib-compass to a combination of

[grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass)

which is using libsass instead of the ruby version, and to get all the magic from compass, we included

[compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins)

and it worked just fine. You should definitely try it out, we reduced our compilation time from more than 40sec down to just 500-600ms.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Here's a node module that automagically imports the lib mentioned above into your grunt enviroment:

https://github.com/haithembelhaj/compass-importer

**UPDATE**

Creating a port to libsass is clearly on the creators mind: https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1916

Comment: Yup, that's the direction I'm heading. Though things like sprite generation have [to be replaced with other tools](https://github.com/guardian/frontend/tree/master/tools/sprites)

Comment: Absolutely blew my mind when this worked for me, with literally no changes other than removing compass and getting 5 seconds back in terms of compile-time.

Comment: Upvote for the poor soul who has to maintain 100k lines with 40 seconds of compilation.

Comment: Just made the front-end devs day with this one. Removed `grunt-contrib-compass` & installed `grunt-sass` and `compass-importer`. Didn't even need to change a single line in my scss.

Answer (score 1):

This is answer for sass files (not scss). Please always differentiate them

1. Run in shell

   `bower install compass-sass-mixins`
2. Edit your sass file

   `@import "bower_components/compass-sass-mixins/lib/compass"`

or

1. Run in shell

   `npm i compass-sass-mixins`
2. Edit your sass file

   `@import "node_modules/compass-sass-mixins/lib/compass"`

---

List of functions: 

`https://github.com/askucher/compass-sass-mixins`

Comment: it doesn't matter which file-extension you use, it works for both.