# Node-sass can't find Compass imports

Tags: node.js, compass-sass, compass, node-sass

Is it possible to use Compass with node-sass? It seems node-sass doesn't know how to import the Compass functions out of the box.

```
{
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/box-
shadow\n       Parent style sheet: C:/sandbox/sascar-manager/app/assets/styles/s
ass/project/login.scss\n        on line 1 of sass/project/login.scss\n>> @import
 \"compass/css3/box-shadow\";\n   ^\n",
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/box-shadow\nP
arent style sheet: C:/sandbox/app/app/assets/styles/sass/project/logi
n.scss",
  "column": 1,
  "line": 1,
  "file": "C:/sandbox/app/app/assets/styles/sass/project/login.scss",

  "status": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compass is a collection of sass mixins and functions plus some Ruby extensions. Node-sass is using a libsass library instead, so the Ruby extensions won't work. However, you'll be able to use most of the Compass functionality using [this](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins) project.

Another option is to use [Bourbon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon-libsass) instead of Compass. It has very similar set of mixins directly available as a npm package.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088529/using-libsass-with-compass) quite similar question.

Answer (score -2):

I have wondered this myself. The answer I believe is 'no' when talking of ruby compass, however there are a couple possible options at least worth investigating....

[link to eyeglass on github](http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-reference/eyeglass/) and [compass node](https://github.com/miniflycn/compass-node)

I haven't looked into them closely enough to give you a sure answer, but compass-node may be to compass what node-bourbon is to bourbon, a node-sass port of the library.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10909740)

Comment: Sorry, just trying to help since nobody else was.